# PHP/FPDI: "Warning: fopen: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in." and "atal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: No stream given."

Tags: php, fopen, fpdf, fpdi

I'm trying to get an existing PDF file from a local path in my project, using FPDI/FPDF.
I followed the instructions, trying making it corectly, but always I try the command to import the PDF file (even in my localhost or my server) I receive the message:

> Warning: fopen(doc/certificado.pdf): failed to open stream: No such
> file or directory in D:\Program
> Files\Ampps\www\certificado\utils\fpdi2\src\PdfParser\StreamReader.php
> on line 43
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: No stream given. in
> D:\Program
> Files\Ampps\www\certificado\utils\fpdi2\src\PdfParser\StreamReader.php:105
> Stack trace: #0 D:\Program
> Files\Ampps\www\certificado\utils\fpdi2\src\PdfParser\StreamReader.php(44):
> setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\StreamReader->__construct(false, true) #1
> D:\Program
> Files\Ampps\www\certificado\utils\fpdi2\src\FpdiTrait.php(172):
> setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\StreamReader::createByFile('doc/certificado...')
> #2 D:\Program Files\Ampps\www\certificado\utils\fpdi2\src\FpdiTrait.php(211):
> setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi->getPdfReaderId('doc/certificado...') #3 D:\Program
> Files\Ampps\www\certificado\utils\gerarpdf.php(10):
> setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi->setSourceFile('doc/certificado...') #4 {main}
> thrown in D:\Program
> Files\Ampps\www\certificado\utils\fpdi2\src\PdfParser\StreamReader.php
> on line 105

Here is my code, calling FPDI:

```
<?php
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

require_once('fpdf181/fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi2/src/autoload.php');

$pdf = new Fpdi();

$pdf->AddPage(); 
$pdf->setSourceFile('doc/certificado.pdf'); 
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1); 
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx); 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', '15'); 
$pdf->SetXY(90,50);
$pdf->Write(10,'Test of typing something.');

$pdf->Output('I', 'doc/generated.pdf');

?>
```

Comment: Try using a full filepath, eg `$pdf->setSourceFile(__DIR__ . "/doc/certificado.pdf")`

Comment: Thanks Phil, but still the same error, but now with full filepath described

Comment: Does the PDF file exist and is it readable by the PHP process?

Comment: Yes. It's in the "doc" folder that is in the root folder of the project.

Comment: And what is the location of your `.php` file? Is that _"full filepath described"_ you mentioned above correct for the PDF file you're trying to load?

Comment: Phil, I think I got the problem... Look how the full filepath was showed: "D:\Program Files\Ampps\www\certificado\utils/doc/certificado.pdf"
I'll try to fiz and see if it works.

Comment: PHP can handle both forward and backward slashes when traversing filesystems so that's not the problem. Is that path **exactly** correct? Is your PDF file readable at `D:\Program Files\Ampps\www\certificado\utils\doc\certificado.pdf`? Is the `doc` folder definitely in the `utils` folder?

Comment: It wasn't correct. The folder "doc" is not inside the folder "utils". I created a "doc" folder inside the "utils" for testing and it worked!!!

Comment: In that case, you probably wanted `__DIR__ . "/../doc/certificado.pdf"`

Comment: this worked: $pdf->setSourceFile('..\doc\certificado.pdf'); .

Answer (score 0):

The correction can be done by two options, that has the same result:

```
$pdf->setSourceFile(__DIR__ . "/../doc/certificado.pdf");
or
$pdf->setSourceFile('..\doc\certificado.pdf');
```